# Talking about today's action

Tags: present-tense

**A:** They are not going to school ***today***.
**B:** They don't go to school ***today***.
**C:** They haven't gone to school ***today***.
**D:** They didn't go to school ***today***.

Which one is correct if I want to use ***today***

Comment: They are all correct, although the meanings differ slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use each one, provided that:

**A**
The time is *before* the school's start

**B**
This feels more like a *general* statement, used for example for a national holiday

**C**
The day *isn't* over, and they didn't go to school. (e.g.: if the school is still open in the afternoon, they could still go there)

**D**
The day *is* over, and they didn't go to school